# I have freshly installed Xubuntu 18.04 on an HP Elitebook 745 A2 and cannot get wifi to work

Tags: drivers, broadcom

The wifi adapter is a BCM4352 and I am using the bcmwl-kernel-source driver.  I have tried to follow the advice on this forum in various threads but after two days have not got it to work.

This is what lshw gives;

```
    tim@tim-HP-EliteBook-745-G2:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for tim: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0f0
       version: 0e
       serial: 3c:a8:2a:87:de:28
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:40 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d5804000-d5804fff memory:d5800000-d5803fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 03
       serial: 28:c2:dd:8d:91:a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:47 memory:d0a00000-d0a07fff memory:d0800000-d09fffff
```

This is the output from  lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list

```
    tim@tim-HP-EliteBook-745-G2:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [103c:2154]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

In the drop down menu for networking both 'wi-fi networks' and 'disconnected' are greyed out.

Has anyone any suggestions how I might get this fixed?

Thanks

Today I had another go.

```
tim@tim-HP-EliteBook-745-G2:~$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE        SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0     unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0     unblocked unblocked
 2 wlan      brcmwl-0 unblocked unblocked
```

So nothing is being blocked and I assume that the wireless card is called brcmwl-0

When I run a scan, nothing is found.

```
tim@tim-HP-EliteBook-745-G2:~$ iwlist wlo1 scan
wlo1      No scan results
```

This time the device seems to be called wlo1, not sure if that means anything but I tried to scan brcmwl-0 anyway.

```
tim@tim-HP-EliteBook-745-G2:~$ iwlist brcmwl-0 scan
brcmwl-0  Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

Next I tried to wake up the device.

```
tim@tim-HP-EliteBook-745-G2:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s16f0u2  no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

enp1s0f0  no wireless extensions.

tim@tim-HP-EliteBook-745-G2:~$ sudo ifconfig wlo1 up
tim@tim-HP-EliteBook-745-G2:~$ service network-manager restart
```

Still no joy.  Any ideas anyone?

Now I have tried this.

```
tim@tim-HP-EliteBook-745-G2:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [103c:2154]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
tim@tim-HP-EliteBook-745-G2:~$ sudo modprobe -r bcma
[sudo] password for tim: 
tim@tim-HP-EliteBook-745-G2:~$ sudo modprobe wl
tim@tim-HP-EliteBook-745-G2:~$
```

Still no wifi!

Finally for tonight, I managed to turn off the bcma driver by blacklisting it and now just have wl in operation.

```
tim@tim-HP-EliteBook-745-G2:~$ lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [103c:2154]
    Physical Slot: 0
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 46
    Region 0: Memory at d0a00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Region 2: Memory at d0800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Still nothing.

Comment: So today I had another go.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer has been to but a new WLAN card for £25.  The Intel HP7260AC took less than 5 minutes to fit, was accepted by the BIOS without question and everything is working 100%.  I did a fresh install just to keep it all clean.  Much easier than trying to get driver to work!